# Optimization based integration for MPM

Tags: optimization, algorithms, linear-solver, newton-method, conjugate-gradient

I'm considering implementing (just for simplicity) the unconstrained implicit optimization based integration for Material Point Method as described in [Chenfanfu Jiang's thesis on MPM](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~jteran/student_thesis/jiang.pdf) (the minimization algorithm starts on page 101 – "*A.3.1 Unconstrained minimization*").

I have difficulties understanding how would be the algorithm implemented.

### **Are the statements below (in)correct?**

The goal of the algorithm is obtaining new grid velocities in response to external and internal forces of the material represented by material points.

The function to be minimized is $E(\mathbf{v}) = \sum_i\frac{1}{2}m_{\mathbf{i}} \lVert \mathbf v_i - \mathbf {v_i}^n \rVert + \Phi(\mathbf {x_i}^n + \Delta t\mathbf v_i)$. (from Jiang's thesis)

It's derivative is $\mathbf h(\mathbf v) = \mathbf M\mathbf v - \Delta t \mathbf f(\mathbf x^n + \Delta t \mathbf v) - \mathbf M\mathbf v^n$.

Based on the thesis I assume the approach to minimizing $E$ is by the Newton method. The Newton method requires inverse of hessian $\mathbf{\mathit{H}}$. However we're in fact interested in $\Delta \mathbf v$ that would minimize (the linearization of) $E$, so we can instead solve $\mathbf{\mathit{H}}\Delta \mathbf v=\mathbf h$.

When solving the system via Conjugate gradient, we only need to know the product $\mathbf{\mathit{H}}\Delta \mathbf v$, which can be thought of as differential $\delta \mathbf h = \mathbf M\Delta \mathbf v - \Delta t^2 \delta \mathbf f(\mathbf x^n + \Delta t \mathbf v) = \mathbf{\mathit{H}}\Delta \mathbf v$.

From [[Stomakhin et al. MPM snow paper]](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~jteran/papers/SSCTS13.pdf) we know how to compute $\delta\mathbf{f_i}$ (page 6 – "*6 Stress-based forces and linearization*") – i.e. force differential for the grid velocity at node $\mathbf i$.

**My assumptions:**

1. When solving $\mathbf{\mathit{H}}\Delta \mathbf v=\mathbf h$ via Conjugate Gradient (step 4. in the algorithm)

   1. ${\Delta \mathbf v}$ is a column vector consisting of component-wise grid velocity differentials – $[{\Delta v}_{1x}, {\Delta v}_{1y}, {\Delta  v}_{1z},\,\,\, {\Delta v}_{2x}, {\Delta  v}_{2y}, {\Delta v}_{2z}, \,\,\,\ldots]$ (length of $\Delta \mathbf v$ is therefore $3n$, where $n$ is the number of grid nodes (containing velocity))
   2. When multiplying $\mathbf{\mathit{H}}\Delta \mathbf v$, we're in fact always processing 3 rows at the same time - i.e. we process one grid node at time (which consists of x,y,z velocity components).
   3. When computing residual $\mathbf r = \mathbf h - \mathbf{\mathit{H}}\Delta \mathbf v$, we can compute its consecutive 3 components corresponding to grid node $\mathbf i$ (like in assumption 1.1.) by writing $\mathbf{r_i} = \left(m_{\mathbf i}\mathbf v_{\mathbf i} - \Delta t \mathbf f_{\mathbf i}(\mathbf x^n_{\mathbf i} + \Delta t \mathbf v_{\mathbf i}) - m_{\mathbf i}\mathbf {v_{\mathbf i}}^n\right) - \left(m_{\mathbf i}\Delta\mathbf v_{\mathbf i} - \Delta t^2 \delta \mathbf {f_i}(\mathbf x^n_{\mathbf i} + \Delta t \mathbf v_{\mathbf i})\right)$.
   4. When computing $\mathbf r \cdot \mathbf r$, I ignore the fact that each 3 consecutive elements of vector $\mathbf r$ correspond to 1 grid node, and just compute the dot product like with any other vector.

**Additional question:**

1. Is the line search (step 7 of the algorithm) necessary?

Comment: Line searches are never necessary unless you want the algorithm to converge to a solution.

Comment: Thank you @MarkL.Stone. Does this mean that without line search I would not be able to get anywhere near the solution - i.e. line search is not just for speeding the optimization up, but it's **needed** in order to find meaningful approximations of solutions?

Comment: Without line search, the algorithm may or may nor converge. So use line search. It's possible that without line search, you can be lucky and the algorithm converges to a solution.